# printing pdf in oracle apex 5.1 using bi publisher 11g trial edition

Tags: bi-publisher

i already installed web logic server and bi publisher but when i open the localhost:7001/xmlpserver/ 
this was the result 
[image: screenshot]
how to fix this? i need to generate a pdf report from oracle apex 5.1

the oracle web logic server is opening 
[image: screenshot]

this was the result when i start the startWebLogic.cmd
[image: screenshot]

and this was the result when i start the oracle bi publisher from my desktop shortcut
[image: screenshot]

how to solve my problem and start generating pdf reports and forms from my oracle apex 5.1?

Answer (score 0):

hi you need to open internal apex page
manage instance -> instance settings - > report printing
print server = oracle BI publisher -- print server protocol = htt --print server host address = youraddress --> print server port = 7001 --> print server script = /xmlserver/convert --> print timeout = 300